# Inference on Stock Returns (Newey & West t-statistics)

Tags: equities

For my project, I want to determine if the yearly returns of some decile portfolios (*calculated with the monthly returns over the last 50 years*) are not significantly different from my predicted returns (*based on my mathematical model*). Initially, I had two ideas:

(1) My first thought was to assume all monthly returns are IID. Then I could easily argue with the **CLT** that the portfolio return will be **approximately t-distributed** and could calculate a confidence interval as well as a hypothesis test. However, this assumption is too strong for my purpose, especially while dealing with time series.

(2) My second thought was to use the **Newey and West (1987) t-statistics** which is well-used in papers with the emphasis on determining the predictive power of some factors on stock returns. Since the Newy-West procedure is used in regressions to obtain HAC standard errors, there would be the option to regress the monthly stock returns on a vector only consisting of ones (1,...,1) to obtain the intercept, which will equal to the sample mean. However, most papers refer to some lags (normally between 4 and 6), which I don't understand with my basic statistical knowledge. Also, I don't know **how I can compute whether the sample mean is significantly different from my prediction based on the HAC standard errors in R**.

I would greatly appreciate it if somebody could help me with the commands I should use in R. Or maybe, there would be even a better test to determine if my prediction is valid instead of simply computing if the sample mean is not significantly different from my prediction.

Any help would be desperately needed :D